# LD_PRELOAD and extern variables

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

Say, I want to modify `mmap`. So I create a new shared object file for that purpose and use LD_PRELOAD to use it instead of the original `mmap`. However, I need to refer to a variable which is my program files. How can I do that? I read somewhere about weak references. Is that the way to do that. I don't think you can use `extern` because you compile the shared library separately than your program. Any advice on this?

Secondly, does `LD_PRELOAD` only affects the usage of `mmap` in your code, or also for example `mmap` called from within the standard library `libc.so` that your code utilizes?

Comment: Do you have the source of your program ? If yes, why do you want to use `LD_PRELOAD` instead of overwriting `mmap()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Using `LD_PRELOAD` will affect *any* call to function that has to be located dynamically, regardless of whether it is in your own code or in a shared library loaded by your code.  You can use `LD_DEBUG` to see exactly where things are finding symbols.  Take a look at:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=help ls
```

This will show you the available debugging options.  Note that `ls` here could be any dynamically linked executable.

I'm not sure entirely sure about the first part of your question.  Have you tried using `dlsym()` to look up the variable?